# Laravel validación con form request en dos tablas

Tags: php, laravel, validación

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Hola, para el siguiente caso necesito validar en el form request que un usuario solo pueda registrarse a las sucursales de una empresa, que sea único para empresa, pero como en mi tabla de usuarios solo tengo la fk_sucursal no puedo validar que el usuario sea único en una empresa, trate de hacer con join pero no me funciona, alguna idea de como pueda conseguirlo?
Puedo hacer una doble validación si tengo acceso a fk_empresa desde la tabla usuarios así:

```
'fk_sucursal' => 'required|unique:usuarios,fk_sucursal,NULL,idusuario,fk_empresa,' . $this->fk_empresa,
```

Pero no consigo hacerlo.

Comment: El usuario directamente no esta relacionado con la empresa, quien esta relacionado directamente con la empresa es la sucursal, Entonces, lo que puedes hacer es obtener el id de la sucursal y posteriormente ese idsucursal consultarlo a empresas, y de esa forma obtienes la empresa y conoces el usuario tambien

Comment: Si eso lo puedo hacer con una consulta normal sql, pero me gustaría saber como implementar eso con la forma que trabaja laravel, algo como ese ejemplo que puse.